# How do I set global cmake flags catkin

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
So far I have only used catkin to do a normal build using catkin_make and a release build using catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release.

However, I would like to set more CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and various other options globally for multiple packages in my workspace. How do I do this?

Do I modify the top level cmake? Are there any examples for the same?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201694/how-do-i-set-global-cmake-flags-catkin/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make --help` will show that it accepts any CMake arguments with `-Dname=value`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2015-01-25**:
Thank you Dirk. Would it be possible to set these flags in /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake? Or override the CMakeLists.txt in your workspace?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-01-25**:
Technically yes, you can replace the symlink of the CMake file in the root of your workspace with a modified version. Or even change the system wide file. But I would recommend passing the parameter once - it is persistent and you don't have to pass it again.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-25**:
I would recommend a CMake toolchain file for this. It will allow you to set settings for all packages.

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2015-01-25**:
Great answers. Dirk, its good to know I only have to do this once.

William, so I do catkin_make -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/myToolChain.cmake. In this file I can enter lines like: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}). Is this correct?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-25**:
Something like that, the toolchain file is mostly for cross-compiling, but you could use it for this. I'd suggesting looking at: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2015-01-25**:
Thank you guys. Will add a note somewhere in the wiki when I get it running